# How do i solve stacks and queues data structure?

Tags: python-3.x, stack, queue

```
import sys

def __init__(self):
    self.__stack = []
    self.__queue = []

def pushCharacter(self, ch):
    self.__stack.append(ch)

def enqueueCharacter(self, ch):
    self.__queue.insert(0, ch)


def popCharacter(self):
    return self.__stack.pop()

def dequeueCharacter(self):
    return self.__queue.pop()

s=input()


obj=Solution()   

l=len(s)


for i in range(l):

obj.pushCharacter(s[i])
obj.enqueueCharacter(s[i])

isPalindrome=True

for i in range(l // 2):

if obj.popCharacter()!=obj.dequeueCharacter():

    isPalindrome=False

    break
   if isPalindrome:

print("The word, "+s+", is a palindrome.")

else:

print("The word, "+s+", is not a palindrome.")
```

This is an hackerrank problem

Sample Input  : racecar

output : The word, racecar, is a palindrome.

But i'm getting compilation error as

**Sorry: TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation (solution.py, line** 4)

How do get rid of the error?

Comment: Please check your question. Where is the class?

Answer (score 1):

You've got multiple problems with indentation in your code -- basically with any if statement, for loop, etc. the lines following it that are part of its code block need to be indented, for example

```
for i in range(l):

obj.pushCharacter(s[i])
obj.enqueueCharacter(s[i])
```

should actually be

```
for i in range(l):
    obj.pushCharacter(s[i])
    obj.enqueueCharacter(s[i])
```

Another big problem is that your Solution class is missing the line

```
class Solution(object):
```

at the beginning, and also after you put it in you need to indent all of its methods.